# Show that $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ if and only if $a > b$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
\hfill x^a\text{cos}(1/x^b)    \hfill & \text{ if $0 < x \leq 1$ } \\
0 \hfill & \text{ if $x = 0$ } \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$. **Prove:** $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ if and only if $a>b$. Do so by considering the intervals which $f$ is monotonic.

Want to show: $(\Leftarrow)$ Assuming $a > b$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all partitions on $[a,b]$ we have that $\sum_{1}^{n} |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| \leq M$ or equivalently, $f$ is continuous and $f'$ is bounded on $(0,1)$. And the converse ($\Rightarrow): f \in BV[a,b]$ implies $a > b$.

We know: The amplitude of $f$ is governed by the curve $x^a$. The derivative of $f$ is $f'(x) = ax^{a-1}cos(x^{-b})+bx^{a-b-1}sin(x^{-b})$. If $a > b$, we have $a - b > 0 \Rightarrow a - b - 1 > -1$. On the other hand, if $a \leq b$ then $a - b - 1 \leq -1$.

...

Not sure how to progress

Comment: For the case $a\leq b$ I think it is enough to consider points $x_k$ such that $\frac1{x_k}=k\pi$.  For $a>b$ I think you can show that $f$ is absolutely continuous because $f(x)=\int_a^xf'(t)\,dt$ then, and absolute continuity implies bounded variation.