# How to prove $F(x) $ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ if and only if $a>b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

\begin{equation}
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^a \sin(x^{-b})& 0<x\leq 1;\\
0&  x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I wonder how to prove $F(x) $ is bounded variation on $[0,1]$ if and only if $a>b$.

There is a conclusion that $f(x)\in BV[a,b]$ if $f$ is differentiable at every point, and $f'$ is bounded on$[a,b]$, by which ,I guess, we may  prove our given $F(x)\in BV[0,1]$.

I tried by using the conclusion above, but I get the derivative of $F(x)$ at $x=0$ is $x^{a-1}\sin(x^{-b})$, which seems that we need to classify that $b>0$,$b=0$,or $b<0$, and we need to handle the term $x^{a-b-1}$ which has bounded derivative on$[0,1]$ if and only if $a>b+1$. I cannot work it out in this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that f
is of bounded variation on [0,1] if and only if a>b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146713/show-that-f-is-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1-if-and-only-if-a-b).

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996653/when-is-fx-xa-sinx-b-with-f0-0-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa